# What are valid uses of U+0080 through U+009F?

Tags: unicode

I'm making a virtual computer with a custom font and programming environment ([Mini Micro](https://miniscript.org/MiniMicro)), all Unicode based.  I have need for a few custom glyphs in my environment.  I know about the [Private Use Areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas), but I'm wondering about the "control" code points at U+0080 through U+009F.  I can't find any documentation on what these points are for beyond "control".

Would it be a gross abuse of Unicode to tuck a few of my custom glyphs in there?  What *would* be a proper use of them?

Comment: The entire point of Unicode was to find a solution to the disastrous "meh, I'll make it mean what I want" practice.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C1_set

Comment: Thank you, this is a great resource I failed to find in my searching.  Since I am making a block-oriented terminal, some of these might actually be useful.  If you make this an Answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia lists [their meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)). You get 2 of them for your use, U+0091 and U+0092.

Comment: So it does!  I don't know why I didn't find that in my searching.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 0x80 - 0x9F range you referto to is generally called the [C1 control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C1_control_codes_for_general_use).  Like other control codes, the C1s are for **code extension**, and by their very nature, some are generally left open for further expansion and thus have only vague standardization.

The original and most comprehensive reference is probably [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/#:%7E:text=ECMA-48.%20Control%20functions%20for%20coded%20character%20sets.%205th,data%20for%20interchange%2C%20in%20particular%20with%20character-imaging%20devices.) - up to the Fifth Edition in June 1991.  (The link takes you to a free download in PDF format.)

For additional glyphs, C1 codes would **not** be appropriate.  In effect, the whole idea of control codes is that they are the special case of non-graphical codes.

UNICODE has continued to evolve, with an emoji block that has a lot of "characters" you might not expect.  Let's try one:   it is officially called the GemStone Emoji.  I used this [copy/paste website](https://getemoji.com/) to insert it, you might look to see if something you can use has been standardized in the Emoji code block.

One of the interesting things about the emoji characters is that they are double-wide, even in a fixed-width font.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft uses them for smart quotes the Euro and a few other symbols in its latin-1 extension [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). As this character encoding is frequently reported as latin-1 using these code points for other uses can cause problems, especially as latin-1 is supposed to be code point equivalent to Unicode. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) Wikipedia page gives some history and the meanings of these control characters.